# Randomly selecting points within polygons in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, select, random

[image: polygon buffers and points]

I have 131 polygons (point buffers) and need to randomly select a point within each buffer. Seems like it should be easy but can't find any solutions online. Running 10.5

Comment: Have you tried the solutions described here?: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000013141

Comment: @Iridium I was also going to mention that too. After some setup of fields, using the Select By Attributes workflow, a model could be generated to do this.

Comment: both solutions work for randomly selecting points, I actually used the first one to select the 131 points that were buffered to create the polygons. Now I need to select a random point within each polygon, which neither of the solutions proposed addresses

Comment: @AlecFo But you could use a similar approach to do exactly that: for each polygon you do a subset of the points with the "Select By Location" tool. Then you select a random point from the subset with the method you already used before. Now you have to do the same for every polygon. You can do the iteration with the ModelBuilder or directly with Python, but the principle is the same as before.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I have used a free add-in called Sampling Design Tool (http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=ecbe1fc44f35465f9dea42ef9b63e785) which should do what you’re after. It is compatible with version 10.x and higher.